# Using Java, how do I check using orignal image that if shape01 (circle) exists in image02 (square) after converting both into binary images?

Tags: java, opencv

I am newbie to openCV and JAVA. It is been two days I am searching for the solutions continuously.

I want to check form original image that red circle exists inside the square getting following binary images. I am able to get binary images.

See:

[image: Images]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know OpenCV, but what I can see is, there are at least 2 interesting methods regarding edge detection:

[HoughCircles](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#HoughCircles(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20int,%20int)) and [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#findContours(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20java.util.List,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20int,%20org.opencv.core.Point)).

Try to get them working on your images and come back to ask with code.